# Lucas-Kanade Optical Flow: Turning U and V into pixel locations

Tags: python, opticalflow

I am working on implementing Lucas-Kanade in python for an assignment but I am having trouble understanding how to turn the outputs (u and v) into a pixel location as seen in the first example (moving cars) on the [tutorial page](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html). In the example, the outputs of `cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK` are automatically turned into pixel locations, but my code gives me u and v values that are mostly very small (less than 1). I can't post the code I wrote, but it is very similar to [this implementation](http://ascratchpad.blogspot.com/2011/10/optical-flow-lucas-kanade-in-python.html):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as si
from PIL import Image

def gauss_kern():
   h1 = 15
   h2 = 15
   x, y = np.mgrid[0:h2, 0:h1]
   x = x-h2/2
   y = y-h1/2
   sigma = 1.5
   g = np.exp( -( x**2 + y**2 ) / (2*sigma**2) );
   return g / g.sum()

def deriv(im1, im2):
   g = gauss_kern()
   Img_smooth = si.convolve(im1,g,mode='same')
   fx,fy=np.gradient(Img_smooth)  
   ft = si.convolve2d(im1, 0.25 * np.ones((2,2))) + \
       si.convolve2d(im2, -0.25 * np.ones((2,2)))

   fx = fx[0:fx.shape[0]-1, 0:fx.shape[1]-1]  
   fy = fy[0:fy.shape[0]-1, 0:fy.shape[1]-1];
   ft = ft[0:ft.shape[0]-1, 0:ft.shape[1]-1];
   return fx, fy, ft

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as si
from PIL import Image
import deriv
import numpy.linalg as lin

def lk(im1, im2, i, j, window_size) :
   fx, fy, ft = deriv.deriv(im1, im2)
   halfWindow = np.floor(window_size/2)
   curFx = fx[i-halfWindow-1:i+halfWindow,
              j-halfWindow-1:j+halfWindow]
   curFy = fy[i-halfWindow-1:i+halfWindow,
              j-halfWindow-1:j+halfWindow]
   curFt = ft[i-halfWindow-1:i+halfWindow,
              j-halfWindow-1:j+halfWindow]
   curFx = curFx.T
   curFy = curFy.T
   curFt = curFt.T

   curFx = curFx.flatten(order='F')
   curFy = curFy.flatten(order='F')
   curFt = -curFt.flatten(order='F')

   A = np.vstack((curFx, curFy)).T
   U = np.dot(np.dot(lin.pinv(np.dot(A.T,A)),A.T),curFt)
   return U[0], U[1]
```

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? I am working on an optical flow implementation from scratch as well and am running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected. I am working on the same problem. If you check calcOpticalFlowPyrLK, you'll see that it has some small deltas as well.
Just make sure you don't lose those floating points by rounding them in every iteration.